# Split payment method column into two columns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have data which has a `Payment Method`, containing `Advance` and `Royalty` in rows. I want to split that in two columns `Advance` and `Royalty`.

This is my sample data:

[image]

I would like the output as attached in Power BI:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Next time do not post your sample data as images, please!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

You can add columns to your model in different ways - to add a [conditional column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/add-conditional-column) or a [custom column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/add-custom-column) with M in Power Query Editor, or to add a [calculated column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-tutorial-create-calculated-columns) or [measure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-tutorial-create-measures) with DAX. In this case I will recommend you to add two conditional columns. Click on `Transform data` button in the ribbon to open `Power Query Editor` and then from `Add Column` tab click `Conditional Column`. Name it `Advance`, select `Payment Method to be` Advance`and set the output to be`Advance`:

[image]

Do the same again, but this time for `Royalty` payment type:

[image]

And you will get the desired result:

[image]